# Pass sha1 password to PasswordSignInAsync

Tags: c#, hash, sha1, asp.net-identity-2

My company Hired an expert in web security. He overviewed our login page and says that the password is better to be hash and send to server. I told him that we are going to buy SSL, but he insist that even though SSL, it's better to not send a clean text as password to the sever. He also said that he can hack SSL in 10 minutes but with hash password it's one more step for hacker to hack our web site.

So with that said, I'm using ASP.NET Identity 2 in my program and i'm going to use sha1 for hashing password in user's browser. But i have no idea how to pass this hash password to `PasswordSignInAsync` method.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Your security "expert" is an idiot.

Comment: @DavidG He actually shutdown several of over servers in like two minutes

Comment: @DavidG I'm guessing that your referring to "hacking SSL in 10mins"  but sending passwords in clear text over SSL is not good idea.

Comment: @DavidG Sorry, I'm wrong. I'm not sure what I was going on about. I'm guessing it was man in the middle attacks and fake CA's but even if the password was hashed client-side and then re-hashed with salt server-side, a hacker would already have the original hash which he would just post to the Action.

Comment: @Kitson88 In that case, we can delete our comments and pretend this never happened!

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense to hash the password on the login page before sending it to the server.

An attacker who can "hack SSL" and intercept your traffic, can now intercept the hashed password and simply replay the login attempt with that hashed password as opposed to the plaintext variant. Hashing offers no additional security whatsoever here.